# An error occured while updating some of the page xhr cancelled with Submit button

Tags: xpages

Apparenty there seems to be some sort of problem in xpages with submit buttons and IE.  So I had to set the submit button as follows.

```
<xp:button value="Submit" id="button2" type="submit">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelErrMsg" immediate="false" save="true">
```

When I do I get "an error occured while updating some of the page xhr cancelled"  then pressing enter or clicking the button.  As long as the button is not type submit it works fine but of course I need to click the button and I would like to have the option of pressing enter.

The submit button is the only button on the form.

Update:  Here is a full example demonstrating the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">Unique Number:&#160;

    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{javascript:@Unique();}"></xp:text>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:button id="button1" value="Update" type="submit">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="computedField1">
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An error occurs because of the combination of a sumbit button and a partial refresh.

The partial refresh is processed asynchronously, which means that the partial refresh (a xhr call) is sent to the server and then let the browser continue "his work". Instead of waiting for the response the form is now submitted, and the xhr call is canceled.
The cancellation of the xhr call pops up the alert.

There are two workarounds:

1. Instead of performing an asynchronous xhr call, do a synchronous call.
2. Override the Error method of the partial refresh

   ```
   <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
    refreshMode="partial" refreshId="computedField1" onError="return" > 
   </xp:eventHandler>
   ```

**UPDATE 21.06.2013**

Here is the code for doing a sync xhr call:

```
// --- hijack dojo XHR calls
if( !dojo._xhr )
    dojo._xhr = dojo.xhr; 

var loadOld;

function hijacked( response, ioArgs ){
   dojo.xhr = dojo._xhr;
   delete dojo._xhr;
   loadOld( response, ioArgs ); // call the original function    
}

dojo.xhr = function( mode, args, bool ){
    args["sync"] = true;
    loadOld = args["load"];
    args["load"] = hijacked;

    dojo._xhr( mode, args, bool );
}
```

The code overwrites the exsiting Dojo functions for xhr Calls to set the required parameter *sync* to *true*. If the partial refresh is finished the original functionality is restored.

Comment: I went with #2.  The only issue is that it blanks out my password fields, if I get an error (passwords don't match, wrong current password etc.).  How do I implement option #1?

Answer (score 1):

When you set it to refreshMode="full" then you will get the full error message. The "an error occurred" message is displayed when the submit results in a Error condition, that would show in a full submission. Change it and see the error message.

Comment: I had it set to full and when I did, I saw no error or anything.  But I can't keep it at full.  For some reason a full refresh causes my page to be submitted twice when executed on on reverese proxy server.   So I need to use partial refresh.  Issue is only occuring when I have type = "submit"